# Ошибка unknown encoding: us-ascii при работе с openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, кодировка, openpyxl

Ошибка снизу

LookupError: unknown encoding: us-ascii

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.styles import Font



# Функция создания таблицы
def create_sheet():
    # Создание книги
    book = Workbook()
    list = book.active

    data = [
        ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000, 100, 16],
        ['Pears', 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 23, 15],
        ['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000, 44, 12],
        ['Oranges', 500, 300, 200, 700, 55, 11]
    ]
    # Добавление заголовков столбцов

    # Добавление данных в таблицу
    for row in data:
        list.append(row)

    # Создание обьекта таблицы
    if not list.tables.get('integration'):
        table = Table(displayName='B1:H14')

        # Стиль по умолчанию
        style = TableStyleInfo(name='TableStyleMedium9', showLastColumn= False,
                               showFirstColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
        table.tableStyleInfo = style
        # добавление таблицы
        list.add_table(table)

    book.save('plan21.xlsx')
    book.close()



create_sheet()
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, полную трассировку ошибки. У меня выдает другую. Что у вас проверяет `if not list.tables.get('integration'):`? Что за странное имя у таблицы `displayName='B1:H14'`? Посмотрите документацию https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet_tables.html.